# Возобновление NSTimer после остановки выполнения приложения

Tags: objective-c, ios

Создаю таймер `NSTimer` в `AppDelegate`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

В другом классе определяю методы для работы с таймером:

```
- (IBAction)doCountdown:(id)sender {
if (appDelegate.timer)
    return;

remainingTicks = 1200;
[self updateLabel];

appDelegate.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimerTick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)handleTimerTick {
remainingTicks--;
[self updateLabel];

if (remainingTicks <= 0) {
    [appDelegate.timer invalidate];
    appDelegate.timer = nil;
}
}

- (void)updateLabel {
NSString *minutes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", remainingTicks / 60];
NSString *seconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", remainingTicks % 60];
NSUInteger myMinute = [minutes intValue];
NSUInteger mySecond = [seconds intValue];
if (myMinute < 10)
    minutes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", remainingTicks / 60];
if (mySecond < 10)
    seconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", remainingTicks % 60];
theLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", minutes, seconds];
}
```

Когда вью загружается, таймер начинает отсчет:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
...
self.theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 6, 100, 30)];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.timer = nil;
[self doCountdown:nil];
...
}
```

Когда приложение сворачивается, выполняется следующий код:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[_timer invalidate];
_timer = nil;
}
```

Проблема в том, чтобы стереть Label при повторном запуске приложения, начать таймер с оставшегося времени и вписать это время в Label. Помогите, пожалуйста. На SO не смогли помочь :(

Answer (score 1):

Если этот `UIViewController` с Label долгоживущий и единственный, где этот таймер нужен почему бы вам просто не:

1. положить таймер в него, а не в AppDelegate
2. подписаться на нофикации `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` и `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`
3. по хандлеру первого стопить таймер, а по второму возобновлять

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Отпишусь по результату.